# Как отключить скролл на body, но разрешить на внутреннем элементе iOS

Tags: ios, прокрутка, hidden, overflow

Есть кнопка, при клике на которую выезжает область сбоку с корзиной. Необходимо, чтобы при клике на эту кнопку у `body` на iOS задавался overflow:hidden, то есть чтобы при активной корзине, прокрутить страницу было невозможно.

Внутри этой корзины есть блок с товарами, добавленными в корзину. У него ограничена высота и есть скролл. Нужно также чтобы этот скролл сохранился.

Проблем с Андроид нет. Там можно при клике на кнопку вызова корзины просто для `html, body` ставить `position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%`. К большому сожалению, такое решение не работает на iOS (iOS12 по крайней мере).

Я перепробовал наверное уже все решения, которые можно найти в интернете. Единственное, которое сработало, но частично:

```
    function preventTouch(e) {
    var cartItems = document.querySelector('.car-items-list');

    if (!e.targetTouches[0].target.closest('.car-items-list')) {
        console.log(e.target);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}


$('.mobileopencart').click(function() {
    $('body').addClass('body-over'); 
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', preventTouch, { passive: false });
});


$('.mobileopencart-on').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('body-over'); 
    window.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventTouch, { passive: false });
});
```

При таком подходе действительно пропадает скролл, если скроллить на всех элементах кроме листа с товарами за счет кода:

```
if (!e.targetTouches[0].target.closest('.car-items-list')) {
        console.log(e.target);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Однако, как только скролл касается листа с товарами, то и `body` начинает скроллиться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое можно применить решение, чтобы можно было скроллить во внутреннем элементе, при этом не затрагивая `body`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*Отлавливаем события touch
    Если тач срабатывает не на том элементе, который нам нужен, отменяем действие по умолчанию
    Если срабатывает на дочернем элементе и доскролили до конца, то отменяем дествие браузера
    Прокрутка вверх отключится
    Для этого высчитываем направление тача исходя из clientY координат и того значение, которое было получено на момент начала тача
    */

   var lastY; //Координата начала тача
    
   function preventTouch(e) {
        var cartItems = document.querySelector('.cart--area .car-items-list');
        console.log(cartItems.scrollHeight);
        console.log(cartItems.offsetHeight);
        if ((!e.targetTouches[0].target.closest('.car-items-list')) || ((cartItems.scrollTop >= (cartItems.scrollHeight - cartItems.offsetHeight)) && ((e.touches[0].clientY - lastY) < 0)) || ((cartItems.scrollTop == 0) && ((e.touches[0].clientY - lastY) > 0)) || (cartItems.offsetHeight == cartItems.scrollHeight)) {
            
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    }

    /*Начало тача*/
    $('.car-items-list').on('touchstart',function(e) {
        lastY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
    });

    $('.mobileopencart').click(function() {
        $('body').addClass('body-over'); //Для Андроид просто класс с overflow:hidden
        window.addEventListener('touchmove', preventTouch, { passive: false });
    });

    $('.mobileopencart-on').click(function() {
        $('body').removeClass('body-over'); //Для Андроид просто класс с overflow:hidden
        window.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventTouch, { passive: false });
    });
```